# Node.js: Issues in using datatypes

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, json, integer

I am developing a REST API in Node.js using AWS Lambda.

Below is my code. I am trying to get a JSON input from the user and save it into the database.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.updateUser = (event, context, callback) => {

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    if (event.body == null && event.body == undefined) {
        var response = errorCodes.missing_parameters;
        callback(null, response)
    }
    else {
        let body = JSON.parse(event.body)
        console.log("body", body);

        let iduser = body.iduser;;
        let first_name = body.first_name;
        let created_date = body.created_date;

        // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
        const sql = "UPDATE user SET first_name=? created_date=? WHERE iduser=? ";
        con.execute(sql, [first_name, created_date, iduser ], function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.toString());

                if (err.toString().indexOf('cannot be null') >= 0) {
                    var response = errorCodes.not_null_parameters;
                    callback(null, response);
                }

                var response = errorCodes.internal_server_error;
                callback(null, response);

            }
            else {
                var response = {
                    "statusCode": 200,
                    "headers": {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    "body": JSON.stringify({ insertId: result.insertId }),
                    "isBase64Encoded": false
                };
                callback(null, response)
            }
        });
    }
};
```

This is my json input

```
{
        "iduser": 3,
        "first_name": "Ranjith",
        "created_date": "2021-07-28 00:00:00",
    }
```

Now, notice my `iduser` is always a number, `first_name` is a string, and the `created_date` is a date.

Right now, there is no data type validation. So i can even pass a text like `hello` to the `created_date` field. There it will not get saved, but the database field will be set to `null`.

Instead, I am thinking of validating the data types before sending. So I can convert the `iduser` to a number, `first_name` to a string and `date_created` to a date field.

I have two questions.

1. Is this data type validation a good practice in Node.JS? I am asking because I am a Java Guy, there things always have a specific data type.
2. If the data type validation is a good thing, How can I convert the above data to the appropriate types?

Comment: Ho is the question related to `java` (aside from you being a java Guy)? --- Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: @Turing85: For the attention of Java community, who may also working in node.js

Comment: Members interested in `node.js` question will be subscribed to the tag. Adding the `java` tag just adds noise (this is how I landed here, and I am not proficient in `node.js`). I would suggest to remove the `java` tag from the question.